# ng-src not binding data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flask

I'm using `ng-repeat` for getting my url dynamically and using `ng-src` to bind that url through angularjs.
Here's the code

```
    <div class="x_panel" ng-repeat="data in allreviewdata|filter:search">
        <div class="x_content">
           <div class=" review-panel">
              <div class="row"style="margin-bottom:30px;" >
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                      <span ng-bind="data.Channel"></span>
                      <span class="name_date" style="font-size:10px; font-color:#DCDCDC;" ng-bind="data.Date">date</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4 pull-right"style="text-align:right;" ng-bind="data.Sentiment">
                 </div>
            </div>
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
            <img ng-src="data.pic_url" alt="logo" width="100px;"class="review-panel-logo">
          </div>
```

But I was unable to get the proper url. I had also used `{{data.pic_url}}` but its giving error. Also its giving this error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xwBe.png)

Can anybody has the solution for this ?

Thank you in advance ..!

Comment: img url path is incorrect i think so...

Comment: @AnilKumarRam I had given the correct path. data.channel is getting the correct value then why not data.pic_url

Comment: @Tarun, Can you open **data.pic_url** value in separate tab?

Comment: try without the port

Comment: @Natiq yes I'm able to open that url in another tab.

Comment: @Tarun, have you tried **src="{{data.pic_url}}"**?, not **ng-src**

Comment: @Natiq Yes I had tried that also ... error - jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'data' is undefined

Comment: can you show us the properties of one of your data objects?

Answer (score 0):

Use in this way

```
<img ng-src="{{data.pic_url}}">
```

Comment: Its giving me this error jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'data' is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You need to have like this,

```
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <img src="http://{{data.pic_url}}"/>
        <img ng-src="http://{{data.pic_url}}"/>
   </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/4zbom6md/)**

Comment: Using {{}} giving me error -  jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'data' is undefined